# C# deep accessing objects performance

Tags: c#, performance, oop

I just want to know which of the following approach is recommended in terms of the performance and best practices. Is there any performance difference?

```
if (objA.objB.objC.objD.objE != null)
{
   objX.var1 = objA.objB.objC.objD.objE.prop1;
   objX.var2 = objA.objB.objC.objD.objE.prop2;
   objX.var3 = objA.objB.objC.objD.objE.prop3 + objA.objB.objC.objD.objE.prop4;

   ......
   ......
}

or

var objonlyE = objA.objB.objC.objD.objE
if (objonlyE != null)
{
   objX.var1 = objonlyE.prop1;
   objX.var2 =  objonlyE.prop2;
   objX.var3 = objonlyE.prop3 + objonlyE.prop4;
   ......
   ......
}
```

Comment: there maybe performance difference but it is unnoticeable.

Comment: it is a bad design sorry to say:(

Comment: Do you know that the compiler will find a direct access path to the properties right?

Comment: Another issue not mentioned is that each line will resolve the values each time which means if another thread modifies the values (or if the property getter modifies them...) then the subsequent lines may yield completely different results. For example, if a second thread swaps `objC` for a different object, then resolving `objE` multiple times _may actually result in different object references_. Your second example eliminates this possibility completely.

Answer (score 7):

The second one is better because you never know what's hiding behind a '.'. It could be a database call or some other expensive operation.

Answer (score 4):

Performance doesn't come into it, as property access is going to be fast (and even if it isn't, it makes little difference if you access the same properties in the same order).

Maintainability and readability are the issues and in that regard, your second option is much better.

Read about the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

> The Law of Demeter (LoD) or Principle of Least Knowledge is a design guideline for developing software, particularly object-oriented programs. In its general form, the LoD is a specific case of loose coupling.

Comment: Yes, but... Why not also answer the question being asked: in C#/.NET, common subexpressions are not eliminated by the compiler, so eliminating them by hand always results in a speed-up. Whether the speed-up is detectable is a different question.

Comment: @romkyns - Exactly. The speedup (?) is not the issue here. I'd rather point out the glaring big issues that do exist with the first approach. And, you never know if a future version of the compiler will not be able to eliminate subexpressions...

Comment: @Oded I doubt a future version will do that, especially if they're properties and not fields. (Personally, I would _not_ want that to happen)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - Not saying it will, just that it is _possible_.

Answer (score 0):

The second is just more easier to use... So, better because you don't repeat your code again and again and again...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer second approach, it is much more readable. In terms of performance it should be unnoticeable, that is in case of regular variables / properties. If there are some performance heavy operations hidden under properties then you should also use second version as it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

In second approach you a have less place for programmer mistakes for example in fist one you could do the following mistake:

```
objX.var1 = objA.objB.objC.objD.objE.prop1;
objX.var2 = objA.objB.**objU**.objD.objE.prop2;
```